# How to detect in HTML5/JQueryMobile App if there is internet connection available?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have basic JQuery Mobile/Javascript HTML5 app. No PhoneGap etc. Just pages in a browser.  I want to sent data to a server if I can detect an available connection?  How an this be detected?  Thanks

Comment: attempt to send the data, read the response code

Comment: I guess that might work.

Comment: All solutions via javascript will basically do that. More or less you make a request somewhere, and if it errors you probably aren't online, so you might as well combine it with the data you wanted to send anyway for a single attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window.navigator.onLine`. It returns true if the device is online, false otherwise. I used it while creating an app in jQuery mobile for iOS and it works.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.onLine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HTML5, you can check the `window.navigator.onLine` boolean status.

```
if (window.navigator.onLine) {
  alert("Online")
} else {
  alert("Offline")
}
```

You can also listen to the offline/online events see here for reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

You can also use [heyoffline.js](https://github.com/oskarkrawczyk/heyoffline.js) if you don't mind having another dependence.

Hope it helps